# M1 Max VERY inconsistent CPU usage running the same Java codes

Tags: java, apple-m1

So I have the same JSON files(over 7000 files) I'm reading using the same Java code that I wrote.

On my M1 Max mac, I'm using 9 threads to read the files, the reading time varies between 3-16 seconds, and the CPU usage ranges from 10-85%.

On my i7-10875H XPS 15, I'm using 15 threads to read the exact same files, the reading time is within 4-5 seconds, and the CPU usage stays on the same level of 80-90%.

The codes on both machines are the same other than the number of threads used. I've done the test thousands of times, and the M1 max Mac's reading time is super inconsistent. According to the VisualVM sampler, it's java.io.FileReader that's taking the extra time, and the mac's CPU usage is very low when the read time is long.

I don't understand why this is happening and does anyone know how to avoid this? Why does the same code have no such issue on the XPS?

Comment: It sounds like your program is I/O bound (vs cpu or memory). It doesn't explain the cause directly, but just highlighting that it's likely nothing to do with threads or cpu usage. Surely when you see 10% cpu that correlates to the longer 16 second runtime - the program is waiting on disk I/O.

Comment: Hi Kaan, thanks for the reply, yes, the file read is a part of a larger project and it's I/O bound, the thing I don't understand is that I'm having no problems on the XPS cause it stays in the 4-5 sec range and predictable, but the M1 Max is just plain unpredictable and it has a better PCIe 4 SSD vs the PCIe 3 SSD on the XPS.

Comment: Just a few ideas.. Are you running latest OS updates? Is Spotlight busy? Maybe background Spotlight indexing is a factor. Can you open "Activity Monitor", then the "Disk" tab, and watch what else is doing I/O?

Comment: Thanks, Kaan, yea, the problem is not M1 max or the machine itself, it's Avast One's file shield, it's been scanning every single file my codes read and write, once it's turned off, everything's fast and normal, didn't know Avast could have posed this kind of impact.